# MVC - Dropdownlist only returns first value, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I create a List in my controller :

```
var items = db.Message
              .Where(m => m.IDClient == id)
              .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = c.IDTexte.ToString(),
                         Text = c.Sujet,    
                     });
ViewBag.ListSujet = items;
```

And my view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListSujet", null, new {  @class = "chosen-select"})
```

But when I select a value, for example the third, it will return only the first value but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit code like this:

```
 ViewBag.ListSujet = new SelectList(db.Message.Where(m => m.IDClient == id), "IDTexte", "Sujet");
```

Comment: @Ricardo Domingues see [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @@RicardoDomingues Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass ItemId in Model and bind this in dropdownlist on viewer.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemID, new SelectList(ListSujet, "ID", "Value", "----Select----"), new { @class = "chosen-select" })
```

I hope it will help you.